# Stick view at the bottom of the fragment of a viewpager inside coordinator layout

Tags: android, android-layout, androiddesignsupport

I have a viewpager which is placed inside a coordinator layout. In a particular fragment of a viewpager i have a recycler view and a view at the bottom of the fragment. The problem is that initially the view at bottom of the fragment is hidden and is visible only when i scroll upwards. I want the view to remain at the bottom of the screen.

> File Name : activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        style="@style/ToolBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/toolbarColor"
        android:contentInsetEnd="16dp"
        android:contentInsetRight="16dp"
        android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="com.dekorate.android.Utils.AppBarLayoutBehavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? The only thing I'm thinking would work is moving the anchored view out of the fragment and into the CoordinatorLayout, but this isn't a feasible solution for me

Comment: @darnmason Implement the AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener in the activity. In the onOffsetChanged method adjust the margin of the view at bottom according the height currently scrolled.

Comment: Cheers, seems to work well enough!

Comment: @arkit may i have code for this? I am facing same issue and can't find any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener in the activity. In the onOffsetChanged method adjust the margin of the view at bottom according the height currently scrolled.

```
@Override
public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int i) {

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams bottomLayoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)fragment.bottomLayout.getLayoutParams();
    bottomLayoutParams.setMargins(0,0,0,(actionBarHeight + i));
    fragment.bottomLayout.setLayoutParams(bottomLayoutParams);

}
```

Here **fragment** is the instance of your fragment and **bottomLayout** is the view at the bottom.